# Changing the origin of 4-wires-touchscreen

Tags: arduino, coordinates, touchscreen

I can read the coordinates of my 4-wires-touchscreen. But I'm getting values like this for each corner (see picture I.)

[image: Picture I.]

Now, I want to get values matched with the size of my touchscreen. I tried this before, but I got a fail measurement of 1 cm, each time I touched the touchscreen.

My code is below:

```
#define Yin  A0
#define Yout A1
#define Xin  A2
#define Xout A3
int values[2];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Xin,  INPUT);
  pinMode(Yin, INPUT);
  pinMode(Xout, INPUT);
  pinMode(Yout, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{   
    pinMode(Yin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Yout, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Yin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Yout, HIGH);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power up
    // Read and store X
    values[0] = analogRead(Xin);
    // Reset Y
    digitalWrite(Yout, LOW);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power down
    pinMode(Yin, INPUT);
    pinMode(Yout, INPUT);
    
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Read Y
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Set X to a gradient
    pinMode(Xin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Xout, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Xin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Xout, HIGH);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power up
    // Read and store Y
    values[1] = analogRead(Yin);
    // Reset X
    digitalWrite(Xout, LOW);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power down
    pinMode(Xin, INPUT);
    pinMode(Xout, INPUT);
    delay(250);
    
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Output our values
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Serial.print(values[0]);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(values[1]);
           
  }
```

My goal is to get the origin of my touchscreen in to the middle and to get my values for each position as centimeters.  (see picture II.)

[image: Picture II.]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do a linear match (yourX = a*measuredX+b - same for Y) but resistive touchscreen calibration is a bit more complex. Here's a bit to read: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt277/slyt277.pdf?ts=1623210456852

Comment: Thank you, I tried something simiular and it worked. Do you also know how to implement this in Simulink? So, if I touch the screen, that I can see the exact position as 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I had to put in the Output of X and Y two lines of extra code.

Look here:

```html
#define Yin  A0
#define Yout A1
#define Xin  A2
#define Xout A3

 double korrX = 1.2;
 double korrY = 1.1;

double values[2];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Xin,  INPUT);
  pinMode(Yin, INPUT);
  pinMode(Xout, INPUT);
  pinMode(Yout, INPUT);
 

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  
    pinMode(Yin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Yout, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Yin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Yout, HIGH);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power up
    // Read and store X
    values[0] = analogRead(Xin);
    values[0] = values[0] -507;
    values[0] = (11.4*values[0]/507)*korrX;
    // Reset Y
    digitalWrite(Yout, LOW);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power down
    pinMode(Yin, INPUT);
    pinMode(Yout, INPUT);
    
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Read Y
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Set X to a gradient
    pinMode(Xin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Xout, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Xin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Xout, HIGH);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power up
    // Read and store Y
    values[1] = analogRead(Yin);
    values[1] = values[1] -501;
    values[1] = (15.2*values[1]/501)*korrY;
    // Reset X
    digitalWrite(Xout, LOW);
    delay(5); // Pause to allow lines to power down
    pinMode(Xin, INPUT);
    pinMode(Xout, INPUT);
    delay(250);
    
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Output our values
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Serial.print(values[0]);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(values[1]);
    
    
  }
```